# When deploying new AWS S3 Buckets via Terraform I receive an error that resource already exists

Tags: amazon-s3, gitlab, terraform

I've created a little test environment, using Gitlab and Terraform to deploy infrastructure to AWS. I'm still very new to this so apologies if this is a stupid question.

I have a file called s3.tf, I created a new AWS bucket in there with no issues at all, pushed the branch to Gitlab and merged it, the pipeline ran and Terraform deployed the new S3 bucket to AWS.

Now, I wanted to test creating another S3 bucket, so I duplicated the code in s3.tf and just adjusted the name of the bucket etc. Now when I merge this pushrequest in Gitlab the pipeline still succeeds and the new bucket was created, but I get this warning/error:

```
│ Error: Error creating S3 bucket: BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou: Your previous request to create the named bucket succeeded and you already own it.
│   status code: 409, request id: TEZR4YQMYQPF6QYD, host id: HXt04y7lxANMaIp94g5rnovGwHduElooxrMGDMCdIfuswmtBAsmRdah3Rkx5cBkzaMfRwbid3l6sGHBPoOG7ew==
│ 
│   with aws_s3_bucket.terraform-state-storage-s3-witcher,
│   on s3.tf line 1, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "terraform-state-storage-s3-witcher":
│    1: resource "aws_s3_bucket" "terraform-state-storage-s3-witcher" {
```

Is it expected that I will see this error every single time I deploy a new S3 bucket? Or can I adjust where the terraform apply runs from that s3.tf file?

Thanks!

(Current contents of s3.tf):

```
  resource "aws_s3_bucket" "terraform-state-storage-s3-witcher" {
  bucket = "gb-terraform-state-s3-witcher"
  versioning {
    # enable with caution, makes deleting S3 buckets tricky
    enabled = false
  }

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = false
  }

  tags = {
    name = "S3 Remote Terraform State Store"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "terraform-state-storage-s3-witcherv2" {
  bucket = "gb-terraform-state-s3-witcherv2"
  versioning {
    # enable with caution, makes deleting S3 buckets tricky
    enabled = false
  }

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = false
  }

  tags = {
    name = "S3 Remote Terraform State Store"
  }
}
```

Comment: That seems improbable unless you are using the same bucket name.

Comment: @MarkoE - apologies if I've not made myself clear, but essentially, every time I add a new bucket to s3.tf it's going to throw up the error at Terraform Apply, to tell me the other buckets already exist - which I obviously know, because they're already in the codebase. I guess I just want to know why Terraform is trying to apply all the code, instead of just the NEW code in that file?

Comment: Do you have a state file for the S3 buckets?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure, where would I find this? I can't see it in my GitLab repo. @MarkoE